# How to throw an Exception if calling AWT code outside EDT thread?

Tags: java, swing, exception, awt, event-dispatch-thread

I've searched this along the way on the net but i haven't found an answer yet.. maybe someone of you guy knows this.

I'm developing a swing desktop like application; since I know that swing is not thread-safe (and if I call a method on a JComponent outside the EDT there is always the chance to get a deadlock with the EDT itself), I would like to have an exception thrown by the thread that is trying to call that method.. let me explain better:

suppose I have 2 threads: the EDT and a background worker ("BW").
If I call, for instance, `JButton.setText()`, or `JButton.setIcon()` within the BW there is a chance to get a deadlock with the EDT. Now I would like that when the BW calls `JButton.setText()` and exception is thrown to indicate that I'm doing very wrong..

I see that C# on VS2008 does this by default (I don't know if there is a way to disable this behaviour, but I think it is very useful to detect bad code). Is there a way to achieve a similar effect in java?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html) which describes a `RepaintManager` which checks Swing threading violations. It will not catch all violations, but most of them.

You can easily adjust that class to throw `Exception`s iso just printing a stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each swing object you have in a Proxy, generated with reflection. Make that proxy compare the thread to the known good EDT thread. If doesn't match throw a RuntimeException.

Comment: Or you can use aspectj or some such to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread%28%29). Calling this will return `true` if the call is made from within EDT, `false` otherwise.

It will do exactly what you want, the problem is you will probably have to make such calls in multiple places of your code; it's more work.